# What are the differences between these 2 LINQ statements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

First (which works) :

```
IEnumerable<PacchettoOfferta> PacchettiTemp = from PacchettoOfferta a in SottoPagina.PacchettiOfferte
                                              select a;
Pacchetti = Pacchetti.Union(PacchettiTemp);
```

Second (which doesn't work, `Unable to cast object of type`) :

```
Pacchetti = Pacchetti.Union((IEnumerable<PacchettoOfferta>)SottoPagina.PacchettiOfferte);
```

Why? I'd like to use the second statement... What are the differences? And what do I need to do in order to fix it?

Comment: What is the type of "SottoPagina.PacchettiOfferte"?

Comment: @eyossi: I suspect `IEnumerable`. Non-generic, hence the need for the type specifier :)

Comment: I think that the answer below will solve your problem, but if not, specify it's type and it will be easy to solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `SottoPagina.PacchettiOfferte` is not an `IEnumerable<PacchettoOfferta>`, you can't cast it to this type.

Try using the [Enumerable.Cast Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
Pacchetti = Pacchetti.Union(SottoPagina.PacchettiOfferte.Cast<PacchettoOfferta>());
```

Comment: so it Cast every item in `SottoPagina.PacchettiOfferte` into an `IEnumerable<PacchettoOfferta>`?

Comment: @markzzz: No, it casts every item in `SottoPagina.PacchettiOfferte` into a `PacchettoOfferta`, so the result is an `IEnumerable<PacchettoOfferta>`. This, of course, only works if the items in `SottoPagina.PacchettiOfferte` *can* be cast to a `PacchettoOfferta`.